# Can I estimate synthesized speech duration?

Tags: c#, signals, signal-processing, text-to-speech

I am trying the generate wave file in windows OS from Text with specific duration entered by the user.
     For example If the user wants to "HH:MM:SS" timespan (get the format as Total secs) of wave file .. with the text "I love Stack Overflow" to be looped for "HH:MM:SS".

How can I calculate the duration of Wavfile from the text and and generate the Wavefile with the specific duration and save it to the disk. what algorithm or code I need to follow?

Currently I am using Speech.Synthesis to generate text to wavefile but calculating duration from text seems to be big problem here..

Answer (score 1):

Track progress of speech generation. `SpeakProgressEventArgs` has a `AudioPosition` property which is a `TimeSpan`. Timings are reset between `Speak` calls so you could use a single `System.Speech.Synthesis.PromptBuilder` for instance to get the whole duration if you have multiple phrases, sentences, ssml markup or zones with different emphasis, volume or rate.

```
  SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
  synth.SpeakProgress += new EventHandler<SpeakProgressEventArgs>(synth_SpeakProgress);
  //
  string s1 = "I love Stack Overflow";
  PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();
  builder.AppendSsmlMarkup("I love <emphasis>Stack Overflow</emphasis>");
  builder.AppendText(s1);
  builder.AppendText(s1, PromptEmphasis.Strong);
  builder.AppendText(s1, PromptRate.ExtraFast);
  builder.AppendText(s1,PromptVolume.Loud);
  //
  synth.Speak(builder);    

static void synth_SpeakProgress (object sender, SpeakProgressEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Speak progress: {0} AudioPosition: {1} Text: {2}", e.CharacterPosition, e.AudioPosition, e.Text);
}
```

[image: audio position progress]

Comment: Hi.. I dont understand here.. I want to generate wave file based on user input.. say if the user wants 6 mins of audio looping "I love stack overflow" for 6 mins.. but here I guess we cannot give that as a input... can give me more example pls.

Comment: Measure length for a single run, speed rate affects length. Do the math and loop for how many times that fits into your interval.

Comment: I found little bit contrary with the above approach.. with the above example Speak progress: 82 AudioPosition: 00:00:00.1000000 Text: I
Speak progress: 84 AudioPosition: 00:00:00.2100000 Text: love
Speak progress: 99 AudioPosition: 00:00:00.4200000 Text: Stack
Speak progress: 105 AudioPosition: 00:00:00.7850000 Text: Overflow takes (.785 ms) but with the Actual Wave file generated for the text "I love stack overflow" it takes 2 secs.

Comment: Obviously that depends on machine performance. Idea was you could use the last (highest) value for AudioPosition.

Comment: You are correct I got your Idea but my question was how to match for 2secs.. what algorithm I need to write? you see above .785ms and 2secs for same text.. how do I match it... Sorry to ask you this since  I am beginner

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly, you want to input a text and find out **the time it takes for the synthesizer voice to speak it out**.

Well that's kind of non deterministic because each recorded voice will pronounce each phoneme in it's own way. So I can say "*I love Stack Overflow*" faster or slower than another person. In order to create the synthesizer, Microsoft used different voices and asked them to speak different texts, and they use the best match to your text when creating the speeches.

Take note that the time to speak each phoneme also differs depending on the text. For example **the "o" time in "flow" is different from the "o" time in "olive"**.

That makes it impossible to estimate the time it takes for the synthesizer to speak your text. You can control the speech pace using **Synthesizer.Rate** parameter but you cannot compute the exact time it will take to speak.

So I think that **without generating a single recording** with the text you want and get the time from there, **you cannot do this very accurately**.

Comment: hi ok thanks.. but lets take an example with microsoft default voice and rate = 0, you mean to tell we cannot calculate the duration.. with any manual algorithm?